# does View in react native work same as Div in HTML?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to render multiple element with different styles but View and child View is not working as div working in html. please guide or share some resources to learn how multiple View work in a return.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View,ScrollView } from 'react-native';
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <View>
 
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text >
                Books are the best Mentors
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View>
            <Text style={{backgroundColor:'red'}} >
                Books are the best Mentors
            </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
          );
        };
        
    

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    container2: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        position:'absolute',
        bottom:0
      },
  });
```

Comment: Can you describe how the results you're getting are different from the results you expect? Also, are you aware that you aren't using `container2` at all? And, only one of you `View`s is marked as `container`

Comment: when apply styling to parent View child View styling doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR `<div>` is not the same as `<View>`**

It looks like the possible issue here is that `<div>` have different default styling, and you should always remember about this. For example the default value for `flexDirection` in RN is `column`, not `row` like we have with `<div>`s.

Even though the official [RN documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view) about `View` tells us this:

> View maps directly to the native view equivalent on whatever platform React Native is running on, whether that is a UIView, `<div>`, android.view, etc.

We should always keep in mind the specifics of the particular platform we work with.

I would also recommend you to check out this [tutorial](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox) regarding *Flex styling* in React Native to get better experience working with it.

Comment: thank you so much. 
one more thing i want to ask is how View and child View work together because when apply styling to parent View child View styling doesn't work.

Comment: Styling in React Native is similar to so-called "inline styling" in HTML (in most cases). So if you set styles to the parent, children won't use that styles. You need to pass styles to children separately.

Comment: separately like this style={{color:'red}} ?